PS: Add-Content Get-Date & concatenate variable
I have a variable called BB_NP and I want to add the contents of that (string) to an output text file with a date/time, so just a basic log file.
Add-Content -Path ".\LogFile.txt" -Value $(Get-Date) ($BB_NP)

Every time I try, no matter what combination (wrapping it or not wrapping, etc),  it can only do one, and not both, I believe it's due to the two different types of data.
How can I have this write to a text file, the date/time and then concatenate the content of BB_NP variable?.
Thanks!.

Use an expandable string literal,  "...":
Add-Content -Path ".\LogFile.txt" -Value "[$(Get-Date)] $BB_NP"


Thank you Mathias, working as expected!, cheers!.

double quotes don't make a string literal tho'

@sirtao A literal is any source code element that maps to some well defined runtime value. The source code syntax @{} is an empty hashtable literal. Perhaps you're confusing literal with verbatim (the label we might use to describe a single-quoted string literal)?

@MathiasR.Jessen yeah, looks like I'm guilty of using the wrong words. I blame it on -LiteralPath for leading me astray! Scoundrel of a parameter!

@sirtao It's actually correct to call it "a literal path" too - adjective vs. noun - I blame English ^_^
